# keep rows from the first file that do not match with second file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files, each has more than 1000 rows,

```
head file 1


3.3    6.6    10    0    0.6    0.33    "Ha1_00044004__C"
0      0       0   10     0       1     "Ha1_00043486__A"
3.3    6.6    10    0    0.6    0.3     "Ha1_00045379__C"
3      6       9    1    0.6    0.4     "Ha1_00045316__C"

head file 2
0    0    0    10    0    1     "Ha1_00043486__A"
0    0    0    10    0    1     "Ha1_00043840__A"
0    0    0    10    0    1     "Ha1_00043671__A"
0    0    0    10    0    1     "Ha1_00044403__A"
3.3    6.6    10    0    0.6    0.3     "Ha1_00045379__C"
3      6       9    1    0.6    0.4     "Ha1_00045316__C"
```

I want to keep only those rows from the file1 that the last column "does not" match with the last column of file2. I would appreciate any help.

my desired output

```
3.3    6.6    10    0    0.6    0.33    "Ha1_00044004__C"
```

Comment: Can you give an example result? Should "file 1" be edited in place as described? Should there be a new file created with unique content from both files?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file

Comment: It is Not the same question!

Comment: What does "intersect" mean in this context? There don't appear to be any strict matches between the last fields in the file fragments you posted

Comment: Yes, because it is only the head of my files. There are more than 1000 rows in each file. I edited my question slightly, I need to keep all rows from the first file, if the last column of file 1 does not match with the last column of file 2. Indeed there are overlapping between the last column of file 1 and 2. –

Comment: @Anna1364 So to get this straight, you want to keep data from `file1` if the data in it's last column  does not match the data in the last column of `file2`? In your examples, nothing will match. Even if it did, what do you want to do with the changes? Write them to another file? Change the first file to mirror the second one?

Comment: @ Nasir Riley, see my edits. it should be clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an associative array (or hash) keyed on the last fields of the first file, then check if the last field of the second file is NOT a valid key:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$NF]++; next} !($NF in a)' file2 file1
3.3    6.6    10    0    0.6    0.33    "Ha1_00044004__C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -vf <(awk '{print $7}' < file2) file1
```